# Specify Gallery image for imageview

Tags: java, android, android-image

first time poster & very new to Android/Java. This board has been a great help, thanks!

I'm having problems trying to use a string to select an exact filename for an image in my device gallery and display it in an imageview - (not browse/pick from the gallery, that works fine) and avoiding deprecated methods like startactivityforresult.

I've set Read permissions for external storage and checked the image & pathname is correct using cx file explorer, but I just can't get the image to load. I've also been trying it with Glide, trying different ways, as below. (Glide works ok when displaying a mipmap image).

I can get the Toast message to show the right path/name, but still nothing in the imageview.

```
// File myfilename = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/DCIM/my_gallery_image.png");
// File myfilename = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath(), "/my_gallery_image.png");
// File myfilename = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString(),"/images/my_gallery_image.png");
// File myfilename = new File(getExternalCacheDir() + "/images/my_gallery_image.png");
// File myfilename = new File ("/mnt/sdcard/0" + "/images/my_gallery_image.png");
// File myfilename = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "/images/my_gallery_image.png");
// File myfilename = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath(), "/images/my_gallery_image.png");
// Uri myfilename = Uri.fromFile( new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/images/my_gallery_image.png"));
//
// GlideApp
// .with(context)
// .load(file)
// .into(imageViewFile);
//
// File myfilename = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator +"/DCIM/my_gallery_image.png");

// Uri imageUri = Uri.fromFile(myfilename);


// Glide.with(this)
// .load(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath(), "/images/my_gallery_image.png"))
// .load (Uri.parse(myfilename))
// .load(Uri.fromFile(myfilename))
// .load (imageUri.getPath())
// .load(imageUri)
// .load(myfilename)
// .load(Uri.parse (myfilename))
// .error(R.mipmap.image_error)
// .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL) 
// .into(imageView_H);

// Toast toastf = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "= " + imageUri.getPath(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
// toastf.show();
```

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 0):

File imgFile = new  File("/sdcard/Images/test_image.jpg");

if(imgFile.exists())
{

```
Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());

ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageviewTest);

myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
```

}

Comment: And also if(imgFile.canRead())

Comment: Thanks, but the image still doesn't load. I added a Toast msg after the 'if exists' and it confirms the image was found, but nothing loads into the imageview

Comment: the toast msg doesn't appear if I try if(imgFile.canRead()){ - so, I guess the image can't be read?? but I've definitely set READ permissions

Comment: the mybitmap also returns 'null' when put in a toast msg - any more ideas please?